# How to change SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow actions language in a German site to English?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

The language of my site collection is German. English is also activated as the alternative language of the site collection. My SharePoint designer is in English but, for this site collection I see the workflow actions in German. Is it possible to change it to English?

I have another site collection with English as the first language and there I don't have this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of

- The SharePoint Designer Workflow actions language depend on the default language that has selected at the time of creating the new site.
- You can’t change SharePoint Workflow Actions language by any means.

So in your case, you could write your workflow steps in English site where all actions displayed with English.
Then move it to the workflow in the Germany site as mentioned at [Change Workflow Actions language in Sharepoint Designer](http://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/16/change-workflow-actions-language-in-sharepoint-designer/)